# Tangent curves in in the plane

Tags: calculus, curves

I need to find Formulas $c_1$ and $c_2: [-1,1] \to\mathbb{R}^2$ for the two curves and check tangency.

[Figure 1.11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIgi2.jpg)

Basically I am stuck. Geometrically I understand both the curves.  And I can solve either by itself.  But I am having trouble getting everything to line up using the $[-1,1]$.

So they line up at the angle ${\pi\over 4}$ but I am having trouble normalizing the input $[-1,1]$ and making them line up

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Can you write an equation for the line? Can you write an equation for the circle? Can you find the $x$ coordinate of the point where they meet? Then check derivatives.

Comment: its not that simple though, I thought it was too.  The length along the curve is longer than the length along the line.  thus as you feed the functions values from [-1,1] you dont simply meet at the point they touch.  

Prof told me to think of the [-1,1] as time and as time progresses the two need not only touch but they must touch at the same time.

Comment: I think I solved it $c_1 (t) = (t, \sqrt{1-2t})$ and $c_2 (t) = (t, -t+\sqrt{2})$

Comment: @mbillion Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 0):

From the given informations it seems that

- $c_1$ is the circle: $x^2+y^2=1$
- $c_2$ is the line $y+x=\sqrt2$

Comment: Geometrically yes,  but that does not make the curve line up at the tangency point.  you would then assume that tangency would occur at 0.5 but that means $c_2 (0.5) = \left(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\right)$ and $c_1 (0.5) = \sqrt{2}-0.5$